# How to hide a sprite for each two shoots?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Am developing a cocos2d game in that am going to shoot a missile with the help of              bullets,here whenever i will shoot the missile, missile has to hide but my problem here is     for each 2 bullet shoots i have to hide one missile.

Here is My code

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(bullet.boundingBox, missile.boundingBox)){  
    target--;  
    [objectiveLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",target]];  
    bullet.visible = NO;  
    missile.visible = NO;  
    continue;  
}
```

This code is for single shoot but i want the same functionality for 2 shoot

Anyone please suggest me how to accomplish this task

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a property to your missile object, and test for it in your code, sort of like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) NSUInteger shotsToDeath;
```

when you initialize the missile :

```
-(id) init {
    if(self=[super init]) {
        // add the following line to your init
        self.shotsToDeath = 1;  // default
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

When you create the missile, you can crank-up the number of shots that will kill him :

```
missile.shotsToDeath = 2;   // if appropriate (depends on difficulty level ?)
```

finally in your routine above :

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(bullet.boundingBox, missile.boundingBox)){  
    missile.shotsToDeath--;
    if(0==missile.shotsToDeath {
        target--;  
        [objectiveLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",target]];  
        missile.visible = NO;  
    }
    bullet.visible = NO;
    continue;
}
```

ed. not tested, not compiled, just for the idea. Beware of decrementing, make certain you dont end up with -1 :)

Comment: Hi YvesLeBorg thanks for your quick reply, but when i try try to  implement the code that you sent it is showing an error like property shotsToDeath is not found on object type missile. So will you please try to get me out of tis problem Thanks in Advance